# oracle partition how to avoid the full table scaninng

Tags: oracle, query-optimization

1. If the table has a partition and a local unique index, is it possible not to create a Primary Key to reduce the automatic update of the global index when adding or deleting partitions?
2. If the table has a unique index, is it possible not to create a Primary Key?
3. There is a need for SQL to change the value of a field in all records in a partition (for example, update table1 set col1 = col2 + col3 where ....; ). How to avoid FULL TABLE SCAN?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a local index for the primary key, then part of that index must be the partitioning key.  It does not have to be the leading column.

```
SQL> create table sales
  2    ( sale_id int,
  3      sale_date date,
  4      other_cols int
  5    )
  6  partition by range ( sale_date )
  7  ( partition p1 values less than ( date '2020-01-01' )
  8  );

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> alter table sales add
  2    constraint sales_pk primary key ( sale_id )
  3    using index local;
alter table sales add
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-14039: partitioning columns must form a subset of key columns of a UNIQUE index


SQL>
SQL> alter table sales add
  2    constraint sales_pk primary key ( sale_id , sale_date)
  3    using index local;

Table altered.
```

This of course means you need to take care with your app because SALE_ID is now no longer declaratively unique, but if its an identity column etc you'll be pretty safe.

Also, global indexes are less sensitive to partition level operations in recent versions because of asynchronous cleanup.

There's a complete tutorial series on Partitioning with videos and scripts at

https://asktom.oracle.com/partitioning-for-developers.htm